# Unexpected error in Share Point server after new user profile service application

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I deleted Existing User Profile service application in Sharepoint central admin and created new UPSApplication. Now when I browse to sharepoint it gives unexpected error

> Error
>
> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 9edb793e-587f-40fd-adfc-a5332a9722d8
>
> Date and Time: 5/30/2012 9:42:46 AM
>
> Go back to site ...

I tried restarting Sharepoint timer in services, restiis, restart app pool..but no luck..

What else can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the SharePoint ULS logs (14/Logs). The Correlation ID listed in the error corresponds with a logged error in the logs.  The full error including stack trace should be included.  Once you know what the actual error was, you can debug from there.

Comment: I used uls viewer and checked it says w3stimer,so i restarted sharepoint timer but not helping

Comment: it's obivously dying on w3timer if the correlation id coincides.  Can you paste the actual event from Unexpected or High Severity rating?

Comment: @NandiniT That tells me nothing, can you post the complete log entry? (there might be multiple log entries using the same correlation token. post them all)

Comment: Cannot connect to the configuration database.

Comment: Check the database - can you connect to it using SSMS?  Check the app pool credentials.  You may need to configure a service account instead of network service.

Comment: i created application pool while creating UPS Application in central admin but,i dont see that app pool in iis...why? then i created new app pool in iis but am i doing right ?

Comment: In that app pool i set it to administrator